# checking if a username exists function returns TRUE even if doesn't exist

Tags: function, return, exists

this function to return number of rows for unique users returns 1 as expected but why when checking against an IF statement to see whether it ===1 (also tried ==1) does it return true even if the user does not exist?

```
function test($user) {
global $link;
$query = "SELECT COUNT('iD') FROM eif WHERE userName = '$user'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link)); //or die(mysql_error());
$return_rows =  mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo $return_rows, " is the number of rows", '<br>'; //this displays "1 is the number of the rows"
return $return_rows;
}


//$user = "austin16";

if(test($user)===1){
echo "yes ",$user," does exist";
} else{ echo " no ",$user," does not exist";}

//if $user="austin316" the IF returns TRUE however if $user="austin" it also returns     TRUE but austin does not exist

?>
```

Many Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will always return one row, `COUNT()` will return the number of rows that match your `WHERE` clause.  You can either select something that is not an aggregate function, or compare to the value that is returned.  The easiest fix would be to change your `COUNT('iD')` to just simply `ID`, so your `$query` line will be `$query = "SELECT iD FROM eif WHERE userName = '$user'";`

This will make it so that your `$return_rows` variable returns the correct value.

Comment: oh for gods sake lol that was tickling me for too long. I had tested with simply ID but could not work out why the COUNT way would not work. Thanks!